# How to create Dial up Connection in Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, bluetooth, internet-connection, tethering

I have Bluetooth dongle attached to my desktop Computer.

I am successfully able to connect it with my mobile phone using Bluetooth Connection, with the Terminal command

```
hcitool cc 00:1D:3B:05:BD:53
```

I am also able to send files from Computer to Mobile Phone and using the utility called Phone-Manager to send sms from Computer.

Now I want to know to start Internet on my Desktop PC using Mobile's GPRS. I am already doing this in Windows XP system since the past 5 years.

Comment: Tethering means sharing the Internet connection of an Internet-capable mobile phone with other devices. (Wikipedia). (For all non native eng. speakers).

Comment: I have laptop with Fedora OS, and I want to create Dial up connection in it. It is not sharing Internet Connection.

Comment: And yet you've tagged the question "internet". Make up your mind.

Comment: What do you mean with this 'Dial up connection'? (Sound almost like in the old days when you had your internet and your phone on the same cable but I suppose you mean something different). Care to explain?

Comment: ya same , old style . connecting your phone line to your modem for internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you connect your phone via USBthere you would be asked to connect via type, there you select Nokia PC suite.

As soon after you would receive a pop up regarding setting of a mobile broadband connection. There you follow the steps. Then after you have o set on your mobile broadband connection on top right corner.